# Aesthetic Constant Vectorial Field 3D-Plot

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus, appearance

I am trying to 3D-Plot a constant Vectorial Field:

[image]

```
VectorPlot3D[{40, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, PlotLegends -> {"Magnetic Field \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(B\), \(\\[LongRightArrow]\)]\) (40 \[Mu]T)"}]
```

But I feel it doesn't look that great, at the center it is a little bit hard to recognize the arrows, I tried to make the arrows a little bit smaller, but it looked weird too. Do you have any suggestions on how to make the plot to look a little bit better?

Answer (score 1):

I do not use `VectorPlot3D`, but playing with some options, you can try changing `VectorScaling`

```
 VectorPlot3D[{40, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

Compare to

```
VectorPlot3D[{40, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can also use default, and change `VectorMarkers`

```
VectorPlot3D[{40, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, 
 VectorMarkers -> "Arrow"]
```

[image]

Combine with `VectorScaling`

```
VectorPlot3D[{40, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, 
 VectorMarkers -> "Arrow", VectorScaling -> "Log"]
```

[image]

And so on. There are many options to try and see which one you prefer.

This is using V 12.1